# Is it possible to change the batch_size half way through a keras graph?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

Is it possible to dynamically alter the batch size half way through a graph?

My system uses words to generate sentence representations and then sentences to generate document representations.

if a document contains 20 sentences, each with 50 words (with a word vector size of 1 for simplicity). And I have a batch size of 10 documents:

- My initial input will be batch_shape = (10 * 20, 50, 1)
- I use an LSTM of batch size=200, time_steps=50, then perform a weighted sum of the hidden outputs to produce fixed length sentence representations of shape (10*20, 100) in parallel
- HERE I WANT TO RESHAPE MY TENSOR TO BE (10, 20, 100)
- In order to feed into a sentence LSTM of batch size 10, time_steps 20
- And perform a weighted sum of the LSTM to produce a document representation

I have tried a reshape layer, and the keras.backend reshape layer, however keras seems to insist on my batch size staying constant (200) throughout the graph even though the operations themselves feel like they should be legal.

The actual error is :
**ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (10, 20, 100) into shape (200, 20, 100).** i.e after letting me reshape my tensor, its now trying to shuffle it back into a tensor with batch size 200

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `tf.reshpae` in your model, which lets you change the shape of tensor even the batch dimension, but you have to make everything consistent so that during the training the data flow is correct.

Here's a dummy network:

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import models
import tensorflow as tf

init_batch_sz = 10 # let's assume initial batch size is 10
ip1 = layers.Input((20,10)) 
dense = layers.Dense(10)(ip1)
res = tf.reshape(dense, (init_batch_sz//2, -1, -1))

model = models.Model(ip1, res)
model.summary()
```

```
Model: "model_3"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_8 (InputLayer)         [(None, 20, 10)]          0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 20, 10)            110       
_________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_Reshape_1 (Tenso [(5, None, None)]         0         
=================================================================
Total params: 110
Trainable params: 110
Non-trainable params: 0
```

But you should not use `fit` to train such a network, as you'll get an error.

Some other options are:

1. Using a dummy 1 batch dimension.

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import models
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


init_batch_sz = 10 # let's assume initial batch size is 10
ip1 = layers.Input((10, 20,10)) 
dense = layers.Dense(10)(ip1)
res = tf.reshape(dense, (-1, init_batch_sz//2, 40, 10)) # you need to make some calculations here to get the correct output_shape

model = models.Model(ip1, res)
model.summary()

x = np.random.randn(1, 10, 20, 10) # dummy 1 batch
y = np.random.randn(1, 5, 40, 10) # dummy 1 batch

model.compile('adam', 'mse')
model.fit(x, y)
```

```
Model: "model_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_2 (InputLayer)         [(None, 10, 20, 10)]      0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 10, 20, 10)        110       
_________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_Reshape_1 (Tenso [(None, 5, 40, 10)]       0         
=================================================================
Total params: 110
Trainable params: 110
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 1.9959

<tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f600d0eb630>
```

Comment: This does work, thanks a lot. As a side note tf.keras.backend.reshape does the same thing as tf.reshape, so I was close to the right idea. The main thing i had wrong was that the input and output batch size of the model still need to be the same.
So i changed it to:

 -> input of shape [batch_size, d1, d2, d3]

 -> reshape [-1, d2, d3]

 -> LSTM output [batch_size*d1, HIDDEN_SIZE]

-> reshape again [batch_size, d1, HIDDEN_SIZE]

I.e. the lack of the first reshape at the start was the main problem. 
Thanks